# R: How to join two different plots in the same pdf page over a loop

Tags: r, ggplot2, lapply

I am interested in visualizing two plots together in the same page. One plot shows Usage of Drugs over time and the other plot shows Occurrence of Resistance over time. The Y-axis scales are very different for both so I think displaying them in separate graphs is useful.

I use the following code to generate the two different graphs for 676 ids(or elements in my data) in to two separate pdfs. This is not helpful when comparing how usage and resistance for one id is varying with time. Instead I would like to generate one pdf and in each page of the pdf, I would like to show the resistance and usage variation over time for the same id/element. So goal is to have 676 pages for 676 ids in my pdf and in each page display the use and resistance for the same id.

I know this can be done using grid.arrange from gridExtra but not sure how to use it in a loop and with lapply.

```
###Resistance
Plot_list1 =list()
#this is the loop
for (i in J0$id){
  temp1 <-  J0%>%
    filter(id==i)%>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Year  , y = Rest)) + 
    geom_line()+
    geom_point()+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2008, 2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018))+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
    theme(legend.position = "none") + 
    ggtitle(i) 
  
  Plot_list1[[i]] <-  temp1
}
##saving the loop in pdf
pdf("Resistance.pdf")
invisible(lapply(Plot_list1, print))
dev.off()

###Usage
Plot_list2 =list()
#this is the loop
for (i in J0$id){
  temp2 <-  J0%>%
    filter(id==i)%>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Year  , y = DUL0)) + 
    geom_line()+
    geom_point()+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(2008, 2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018))+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
    theme(legend.position = "none") + 
    ggtitle(i) 
  
  Plot_list2[[i]] <-  temp2
}
##saving the loop in pdf
pdf("UsageDUL0.pdf")
invisible(lapply(Plot_list2, print))
dev.off()
```

Comment: I actually recommend `patchwork` for combining grobs: while it uses `grid` and such under the hood, in my opinion the interface is a bit nicer and more capable (`</opinion>`). Regardless. as to creating a 676 page pdf, if you use `pdf(..., onefile=TRUE)`, then each plot you render will get its own page. Make sure you `print` each combined plot.

Comment: any tips on how to combine the plots using patchwork? i run two loops to generate the two types of plots. how should i combine the two types of graphs for each id using pathcwork?

Comment: Go through the [*Getting Started*](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/patchwork/vignettes/patchwork.html) vignette and pick what looks best for you. It might be as easy as `gg1 + gg2`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a terse walk-through.

Step 1, generate fake data, plot it individually into `gg1` and `gg2`, then combine them using `patchwork`. This could easily (and perhaps arguably *should*) be broken into multiple stages, but it's small enough to use just one `lapply`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
set.seed(42)
allgg <- lapply(1:3, function(ind) {
  dat <- mtcars[sample(NROW(mtcars), 10),]
  gg1 <- ggplot(dat, aes(disp, mpg)) + geom_point(color = "red") + labs(title = paste("Page ", ind), subtitle = "mpg ~ disp")
  gg2 <- ggplot(dat, aes(qsec, drat)) + geom_point(color = "blue") + labs(subtitle = "drat ~ qsec")
  gg1 / gg2
})
```

Start the pdf file, plot them all, then close the device.

```r
pdf("quux.pdf", onefile = TRUE, width = 6, height = 6)
for (pg in allgg) print(pg)
dev.off()
```

For me, I get a 6x6 (inch) PDF with three pages, looking like:

[image: three pages of a pdf]